# How to pass the CUSTOM_ID property as custom \label when exporting to latex?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I used to be able to pass the `CUSTOM_ID` property as  custom `\label` once exported to LaTeX. A snippet like this:

```
* Introduction
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CUSTOM_ID: custom_label
  :END:
```

Would export to:

```
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec-1}
\label{custom_label}
```

I am using Org-mode version 8.2.7c and that is not the case anymore, the org-mode snippet above exports to:

```
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec-1}
```

Because of that, I need to add custom labels everywhere, like:

```
* Introduction
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CUSTOM_ID: custom_label
  :END:
  \label{custom_label}
```

Is there a better way to pass the `CUSTOM_ID` property with the new `org-latex-export-as-latex` way?

Or, more generally, is there a systematic way to pass any `PROPERTIES` when exporting to LaTeX?

Thank you for any help or pointer I could use.

Comment: But `Go to [[#custom_label]]` exports to `Go to \ref{sec-1}`. Why is not that good enough for you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking. I use `org-mode` to publish books (via LaTeX). Some books are like a dictionary, where each entry has its own key, dictated by the publisher. I need to be able to access those 'keys' (as labels) so to print them properly (as running titles, or in other places).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case you don't notice @nberth 's answer, In current version `Org 8.3.2`, do the following

```
(setq org-latex-prefer-user-labels t)
```

Answer (score 0):

The current development branch of `org-mode` (8.3) allows to use the CUSTOM_ID property for this.

If one must use his own labels in LaTeX export, he could set org-latex-custom-id-as-label to non-nil.

`org-latex-custom-id-as-label` is part of Org v8.3.

The following code:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (let ((org-latex-custom-id-as-label t))
    (insert "* Introduction\n:PROPERTIES:\n:CUSTOM_ID: custom_label\n:END:")
    (org-mode)
    (org-latex-export-as-latex nil nil nil t)))
```

will produce a buffer with the contents

```
\section{Introduction}
\label{custom_label}
```

as desired.

Comment: You need to use `org-latex-prefer-user-labels` as of [this recent commit](http://repo.or.cz/w/org-mode.git/commit/4bbc054bd252b975f483a29515495a9af9329c71).

Comment: Nice! If you make your comment into an answer I could accept it. Thank you.